# Git organisation for a multi-project team

Tags: git

here is another GIT newb'.

- I want to use GIT for our projects.
- The team is not familiar with GIT.

These projects basically consist of some common projects(*) and some applications projects. The applications are using the commons, the commons can use other commons too. By "using" I mean that would be great that they share source code. Or at least that a project could use the compiled dll of a common project.
Here is an example of how I want my folder structure to be:

```
common
+-- basics
    +-- gui
    +-- utils
+-- win
    +-- gui.win
    +-- utils.win

app1
+-- win
    +-- app.win
```

Here the project gui.win needs to use common > gui. The app.win certainly needs gui.win.

## GIT

### submodule

For the GIT repositories I started to look at submodules. But it seems to be about more static libraries. Someone working on the app.win would need a lot of work to pull every other sub-modules and be sure to have the latest version.

### subtree

For these, the only solution seems to involve some scripting to handle the dependencies. Therefore it adds burden to the daily work flow. Getting familiar with GIT will already be enough overhead for our daily work.

### multi-repositories

This solution has a lot of good points. It looks clean. It clearly separate the subject of work etc. But I don't see how to handle the dependencies between projects this way. How could the app.win reference(*) gui.win?

### global repository

Then I am thinking that the only solution is to have a single big repository containing everything. Is that realistic? (to give an order of magnitude: the *common* from this tree should be less than 10 projects, and there would be around 20 applications).
We could then use a *main* branch per application (and one for the *common*) and sub-branches for sub-projects, features or hot-fixes.
We would use tag like "app1.v1.0" to milestone releases.

---

* Since I am working with VisualStudio I am here using some this terminology. Projects are a set of files outputing a library or an application. And references are a link to another projects's output or access to the sourcecode (Like having different *solutions* using same projects)

Answer (score 2):

You can use git submodule for any kind of sub module, it is not limited to static libraries. For example, my `~/.vim` folder is versionned and has several submodules for each plugin I install.

I think it is the preferred solution, as the main repository can remember what revision is used by your project and you can synchronise all the submodules with a single command.

So you can have a team or a person working on a submodule as a project in itself, making changes, commiting and so on. When you want to include the changes, you just have to do it in the main repository, and you don't have to bother yourself with any in-progress version.

Comment: submodules are great if you want to depend on exactly specified states of the submodule. if you do some fast-paced iterative changes to both the application and the library it quickly sucks because you need to register every change multiple times. also the workflow (imho) is not very user-friendly especially novice users can get stuck easily. if you tentatively depend on the latest-greatest version of the libraries the multi-repository-setup is much more lightweight. if your philosophy is that the latest version of the libs is intended to work with every app i would go this way.

Comment: @Geoffroy as commented by mnagel, I read several opinions stated that it is not convenient for frequent updates, specially not for novices because of these multiple updates.

Comment: @mnagel: With the multi-repository solution, for projects which depend on an other project (from another repository) I need to checkout both, separately. Is that what you propose?

Comment: yes, that's how i would do it. keep in mind, that this will not be a perfect fit for everyone and submodules exists for a reason. perhaps i'd write a script to clone them all in one go. for updating them all at once there is https://github.com/mnagel/clustergit (disclosure: i wrote it)

Comment: as long as you manage your submodule as external projects and don't try to work in the submodule, you don't have much work to do. And yes, it is a solution made to have a specified state of the submodule, but this is generally the case as you don't want your deps to change everyday their API. You stick to a revision and eventually update from time to time.